# Sco unix: how to bind bash "end key" to end of line?

Tags: bash

Simple question.
This is my bashrc with bind keys

```
# Binds
bind '"\e[3~": delete-char'
bind '"\e[F~": end-of-line'
bind '"\e[19~":"~"'
```

Delete char works fine
~ works fine, appear when I press F9
But when I press "END" instead to go on end of line it print this

```
[F[F[F[F
```

How to bind END key to end of line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
On a system with right configured key I did

```
bind -P|grep -i end-of-line
```

and I can see the right configuration

```
end-of-line can be found on "\C-e", "\eOF", "\e[4~", "\e[F".
```

So I edit my bashrc on Sco

```
bind '"\e[F": end-of-line'
```

Works fine.

Comment: Or you could have just read the control sequence for that key straight from the `keyboard(HW)` manual page.  (-: